# ORA-28579: network error during callback from external procedure agent...(some issue with heap allocation)

Tags: plsql, oracle-call-interface

**Snippet**: An external C dll which receives a collection(Nested Table of numbers) from PLSQL and does some processing(not shown in the code).

**Issue**: When this external C function is called from PLSQL(library and wrapper created in PLSQL) the numbers are **received** by the C function in the array(on stack). HOWEVER, if I un-comment the commented lines for a dynamic array(on Heap) instead of a static the call fails with:

> `ORA-28579: network error during callback from external procedure agent.`

### Please suggest

```
#define ARRSIZE 107

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)  int ooci_ntm(OCIExtProcContext *context, OCITable* clients)    
{    
  OCIEnv *envhp;   
  OCISvcCtx* svch;   
  OCIError *errhp;    
  double onumm[ARRSIZE]; //Works if its a static array on stack    
  //double* onumm= (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * ARRSIZE);  
  //However, if instead of the above array if the memory is allocated dynamically on heap then the captioned error is thrown.

  sword status;    
  boolean exist;    
  uword nelems;

  OCIExtProcGetEnv (context, &envhp, &svch, &errhp);    
  OCINumber **client_elem = (OCINumber**)malloc(sizeof(OCINumber*) * ARRSIZE);

  status = OCICollGetElemArray(envhp, errhp, clients, index, &exist,  (void**)client_elem, (dvoid **)0, &nelems);    
  status = OCINumberToRealArray(errhp,(const OCINumber**)client_elem,nelems,sizeof(double),(void*)onumm);    
  free(client_elem);

  //free(onumm);

  return size;    
}
```

Comment: When `OCICollGetElemArray` is called, what value is returned in `nelems`?

Comment: Before making a call to OCICollGetElemArray, nelems is assigned:

`OCITableSize(envhp, errhp, clients, &size);`//returns the no. of elements in the nested table in the **size** variable, which is then assigned to nelems
`nelems = size;` //nelems: Maximum number of pointers to both elem and elemind.

After the call nelems retains the value it had been assigned before.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is one of those errors that essentially means any number of things could have gone wrong with the external procedure.

There is a known bug in 10.2.0.3, no idea if it's relevant:

> ORA-28579 occurs when trying to select
>   data from a pipelined table function
>   implemented in "C" using the
>   ODCITable/ANYDATASET interface.
>   ODCITableDescribe works fine but
>   ODCITableFetch generates an ORA-28579
>   error.

Try to  Contact Oracle support